# Nested Quotes - SQL statement in a Javascript alert statement in a PHP print statement

Tags: javascript, php, sql, syntax, quotes

I have two files, the main page file, and another that has a function for generating SQL create table statements. What I want to do is have an alert statement appear after a button click, and have the SQL code displayed (So you can just copy and paste it as is).

This is what I have so far:

**Main file print statement:**

$master is the string being returned from the generate create table function.

```
print "<input type=\"button\" value=\"Generate Create Table\" onclick=\"alert($master);\" >";
```

**Generate Create Table Function**

```
<?php
    function generateCreateTable($resArr, $schema, $name, $type) {
      $strMaster = "";

      $strMaster .= "\"if not exists (select 1 from information_schema.tables where table_schema=    ";
      $strMaster .= "'$schema' and table_name='$name' and TABLE_TYPE='$type')\n";
      $strMaster .= "CREATE TABLE [$schema].[$name] (\n\"";
      return $strMaster;
   }
?>
```

The current code I posted will result in a syntax error, since the escaped double quote closes the start of the alert statement. I've tried many different arrangements of quotes and have also had a result of an unterminated string literal.

How should I be setting up my quotes? I've dealt with a similar issue previously, but lucked out and got the right order after a short while.

Thanks for your time and help!

Comment: AFAIK, alert popups are not usually selectable, which means you can't copy from it easily. You need to use single quotes at the start of alert like `alert('$master')` and remove the `\"` at the beginning and end of `$strMaster`. You will then need to escape the entire `$strMaster` of all quotations using backslash. PHP has a function for this: `addslashes` @ http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php. Then you will need to use `htmlentities` on it as well for the double quotes to escape the HTML attribute quotes. Overall, I think it's a bad idea to inline the click event like this

Comment: I added the single quotes besides $master, removed the \" at the beginning and end of $strMaster, added addslashes with $strMaster as the param when returning, and added htmlentities with the param being the string from addslashes, upon return. When clicking the button I get SyntaxError: unterminated string literal. Everything looks right under the hood, so I'm still stumped as to what the problem is. You're probably right that it's a bad idea. I was hoping this was be a quick thing so I could work on the generator, and have a more permanent solution later on. Thanks for the response!

Comment: Oh you need to supply a special flag to [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) in order to escape single quotes. Try something like `addslashes(htmlentities($strMaster, ENT_QUOTES|ENT_HTML401))`. If you still have problems you should use your browser's view source to check the generated html.